# How can I configure the separator character used for :menuselection:?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx to generate HTML documentation for my project. Under Inline Markup, the Sphinx documentation discusses [:menuselection:](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-menuselection) for marking a sequence of menu selections using markup like:

```
:menuselection:`Start --> Programs`
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<span class="menuselection">Start ‣ Programs</span>
```

i.e. the `-->` gets converted to the small triangle, which I've determined is U+2023, TRIANGULAR BULLET.

That's all well and good, but I'd like to use a different character instead of the triangle. I have searched the Sphinx package and the theme package (sphinx-bootstrap-theme) somewhat exhaustively for 'menuselection', the triangle character, and a few other things, but haven't turned up anything that does the substitution from `-->` to `‣` (nothing obvious to me, anyway). But something must be converting it between my .rst source and the html.

My question is: what, specifically is doing the conversion (sphinx core? HTML writer? Theme JS?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion is done in the `sphinx.roles.menusel_role()` function. You can create your own version of this function with a different separator character and register it to be used.

Add the following to your project's conf.py:

```python
from docutils import nodes, utils
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles
from sphinx.roles import _amp_re

def patched_menusel_role(typ, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    text = utils.unescape(text)
    if typ == 'menuselection':
        text = text.replace('-->', u'\N{RIGHTWARDS ARROW}')  # Here is the patch 
    spans = _amp_re.split(text)  

    node = nodes.emphasis(rawtext=rawtext)
    for i, span in enumerate(spans):
        span = span.replace('&&', '&')
        if i == 0:
            if len(span) > 0:
                textnode = nodes.Text(span)
                node += textnode
            continue
        accel_node = nodes.inline()
        letter_node = nodes.Text(span[0])
        accel_node += letter_node
        accel_node['classes'].append('accelerator')
        node += accel_node
        textnode = nodes.Text(span[1:])
        node += textnode

    node['classes'].append(typ)
    return [node], []

# Use 'patched_menusel_role' function for processing the 'menuselection' role
roles.register_local_role("menuselection", patched_menusel_role)
```

When building html, make sure to `make clean` first so that the updated conf.py is re-parsed with the patch.